# Custom PUT route in json-server by another property than id

Tags: json-server

For science and personal education I wanna know if I can use PUT method without an id or an alias of an id, I just wanna use another property, like name in example below.

```
{
  "/api/*": "/$1",
  "/recipes/:name": "/recipes?name=:name"
}
```

Method:

```
const jsonServerHeaders = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
}

endPointJsonServer: string = 'http://localhost:3000/';

putRecipe(recipe) {
   return this.http.put<any>(`${this.endPointJsonServer}recipes?name=${recipe.name}`, recipe, jsonServerHeaders);
}
```

Server is reached.

```
PUT /recipes?name=Cranberry%20and%20Apple%20Stuffed%20Acorn%20Squash%20Recipe 404 3.597 ms - 2
```

but I think it expects a different route.

Thanks